# Will SharePoint 2016 Support SharePoint 2010 Workflow

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, workflow, designer-workflow, 2016

We are looking to implement a SharePoint 2010 Workflow in SharePoint 2013 which still supports SharePoint 2010 workflow. I was wondering if anyone has heard if SharePoint 2016 will continue to support SharePoint 2010 workflow or are we looking at this as a band-aid for now until we can get the more complicated remote workflow server setup for the 2013 workflow?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What my understanding as Microsoft bring back InfoPath forms in sharePoint 2016. that's mean SharePoint 2010 Workflow will work as some of infopath services required for the Workflow in Sp 2010.

> This leads me to believe that SharePoint 2016 may still be able to run
>   SharePoint 2010 Workflows like 2013 did by default. This is
>   speculating that a SharePoint 2010 to 2016 migration is possible of
>   course.

http://en.share-gate.com/blog/sharepoint-2010-to-sharepoint-2016-migration-a-possibility

Comment: Thanks Waqas. It looks like we'll, at the very least, be good for a while yet.

Answer (score 12):

I have yet to actually deploy it - but I'm pretty sure it will still be around - at minimum to support upgrade.

1. It's not on the deprecated feature list  https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt346112%28v=office.16%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396
2. They still exist in Office 365
3. The biggest reason - they still support database attach upgrades from 2013 - which may contain 2010 workflows.

Comment: Thanks Jesus . . . I wish I could mark multiple posts as the answer. Both you and Waqas' entries as the answer. It's just that Waqas' came in first.